# How to conditionally pipe output in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe, gulp

I want my stream to pipe to another stream only if my first stream satisfy certain conditions.

```
es = require('event-stream');

var checkBuffer = function() {
    return es.map(function(file, cb) {
        if (!file.isBuffer()) {
            cb();
        } else {
            cb(null, file);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = function() { checkBuffer.pipe( mysteryFoo()); return checkBuffer; };
```

I only want to pipe to mysteryFoo only if all if the file piped into checkBuffer passes isBuffer, else I don't want this pipe to happen.

The function that pipes its output to this module is `gulp.src('/some-dest/**')`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if), which uses [gulp-match](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-match) behind the scenes to check if a vinyl file matches a condition.

Example usage pulled from gulp-match:

```
var gulpmatch = require('gulp-match');
var map = require('map-stream');

var condition = true; // TODO: add business logic here

vinylfs.src('path/to/file.js')
    .pipe(map(function (file, cb) {
        var match = gulpmatch(file, condition);
        if (match) {
          // it matched, do stuff
        }
        cb(null, file);
    }));
```